# Form of a real orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**Q.** Let $A$ be a real orthogonal matrix of order $2$ with $|A|=1$. Show that $\exists\theta$ s.t. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\tag{4 marks}$$

**My answer:**

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$. Now, since $A$ is orthogonal, we have,

$$AA^T=I_2\implies \begin{pmatrix}a^2+b^2&ac+bd\\ac+bd&c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{cases}a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1\quad(1)\\ ac+bd=0\qquad\qquad\quad~(2)\end{cases}$$

Also, since $|A|=1$, we have $ad-bc=1\tag3$

Using $(1)$ and $(3)$, we get,

$$(a-d)^2+(b+c)^2=0$$

Since $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ and squares of reals are always non-negative, in order to maintain equality, we must have,

$$a-d=0\text{ and }b+c=0\implies d=a~\land~c=-b$$

Putting this back in $(3)$. we see that it's the equation of the unit circle in the $ab$ plane, hence the parametric representation $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$. The conclusion follows.

---

My question is how much marks this solution will get (in general) ? Also, it'd be nice to see simpler formal proofs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the original post is correct.

Here we present another way forward, which seems fairly efficient.  We note that

$$a^2+b^2=1\implies a=\cos \theta\,\,\text{and}\,\,b=\sin \theta$$

$$c^2+d^2=1\implies c=\cos \phi\,\,\text{and}\,\,d=\sin \phi$$

for some $\theta$ and some $\phi$.

Then, we have

$$ac+bd=0\implies \cos (\theta -\phi)=0\implies \theta -\phi =(2k+1)\pi/2$$

for any integer $k$.

Eliminating $\phi$, we find that $c=\pm \sin \theta$ and $d=\mp \cos \theta$.

We can choose the value of $k$ such that $c=-\sin \theta$ and $d=\cos \theta$ and we are done!

Comment: You can first answer my main question, i.e., how much marks my solution would get out of 4 ? I need to know this for my upcoming exams ( It's my first semester exams, so I'm nervous af ;_; )$$~$$
And yes, your solution was also my first thought but then I thought it'd make the solution more complicated and messier, so I went with the one posted. I forgot to accept this one earlier. Sorry for accepting it late, haha. :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer!  Much appreciative.  As for assessing what mark your answer would receive, I really have no way of knowing that.  I can say that your reasoning and analysis are correct.  So, if the score is based on correctness only, the answer should receive 100 percent.